# Getting Syntax Error in Keyword Class Patterns

Tags: python, namedtuple

**City class and a few instances**

> ```
> import typing
>
> class City(typing.NamedTuple):
>     continent: str
>     name: str
>     country: str
>
>
> cities = [
>     City('Asia', 'Tokyo', 'JP'),
>     City('Asia', 'Delhi', 'IN'),
>     City('North America', 'Mexico City', 'MX'),
>     City('North America', 'New York', 'US'),
>     City('South America', 'São Paulo', 'BR'),
> ]
> ```
>
> The following function should return a list of Asian cities:
>
> ```
> def match_asian_cities():
>     results = []
>     for city in cities:
>         match city:
>             case City(continent='Asia'):
>                 results.append(city)
>     return results
> ```

But on calling `match_asian_cities()` I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Temp/ipykernel_5228/716370306.py, line 20)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5228/716370306.py", line 20
    match city:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> **Need help to fix this. Thanks!**

Comment: Check your python version. `match` is a new as of 3.10

Comment: I don't think python 3.10 has released in ipython yet

Comment: A ``match``/``case`` statement is a waste if you have just a single case. Use a plain ``if``!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about the below

```
import typing

class City(typing.NamedTuple):
    continent: str
    name: str
    country: str


cities = [
    City('Asia', 'Tokyo', 'JP'),
    City('Asia', 'Delhi', 'IN'),
    City('North America', 'Mexico City', 'MX'),
    City('North America', 'New York', 'US'),
    City('South America', 'São Paulo', 'BR'),
]

asian = [c for c in cities if c.continent == 'Asia']
print(asian)
```

output

```
[City(continent='Asia', name='Tokyo', country='JP'), City(continent='Asia', name='Delhi', country='IN')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`match` feature is introduced in `python 3.10.0rc1`. If this version of python available in your system then you can try that. So, for now you can try following code snippet.

**Code:**

```py
import typing

class City(typing.NamedTuple):
    continent: str
    name: str
    country: str


def match_asian_cities(cities):
    results = [city for city in cities if city.continent == 'Asia']
    return results

cities = [
    City('Asia', 'Tokyo', 'JP'),
    City('Asia', 'Delhi', 'IN'),
    City('North America', 'Mexico City', 'MX'),
    City('North America', 'New York', 'US'),
    City('South America', 'São Paulo', 'BR'),
]

print(match_asian_cities(cities))
```

**Output:**

```
[City(continent='Asia', name='Tokyo', country='JP'), City(continent='Asia', name='Delhi', country='IN')]
```